# Update value in localstroage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have below value stored in AngularJs localstroage. How do i update the EmpNo to a different value if EmpNo exist.

```
{"EmployerDetails":{"Distance":30,"EmpLatitude":51.3353899,"EmpLongitude":-0.742856,"EmpNo":4,"Insitution":null,"PlaceName":"Camberley","TalentPoolLicences":[{"Membership":[{"Identity":4,"Name":"Test School Account"}],"TalentPoolType":1},{"Membership":[{"Identity":2,"Name":"North East Hampshire"},{"Identity":4,"Name":"Surrey"},{"Identity":8,"Name":"Surrey"}],"TalentPoolType":3}]},"FacetFilters":{"LastActivity":0,"LocationFilterType":1,"fullorparttime_pex":null,"membership_tpl":["E4","R2","R4","R8"],"religion":null,"soughtphase_swk":null,"soughtrole_swk":null,"soughtsubject_swk":null},"LookingFor":null,"OrderBy":null,"PageIndex":1,"PageSize":40}
```

I have tried below but it doesnt sems to be working:

```
localStorage.setItem(localStorage.key(0).EmployerDetails[EmpNo],999);
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem(EmployerDetails[EmpNo],999);` try this once

Comment: You can't update this way first need to update object and convert it into string.
localStorage.setItem('itemKey', JSON.stringify(yourObject));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the local stored value and then update it as follows,

```
var storedObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yourName');
//update it
storedObj.EmployerDetails.EmpNo = '5';
//store again
localStorage.setItem('yourName', JSON.stringify(storedObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage can able to save only string content. You cannot directly update the value of an object stored in it.

To Store a JSON.

```
var data = {
  "value": 1
};

localStorage.setItem('json', JSON.stringify(data));
```

To Update the value

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('json'));

data.value = 2; // vaue gets updated
```

Store again

```
localStorage.setItem('json', JSON.stringify(data)); // store updated value
```

This is how it works.